# A report for users which is created date is more than or equal to 90 days

Tags: reports-folder

I want create a report for the users in Salesforce which is created date is more than 90 days.

I have tried with `Created Date less than 12/10/2018(let assume this date 90 days before date from today)`. Could someone tell me is the right way that I am following? If not please give me a solution

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Relative Date in your report filter, like TODAY, LAST WEEK, LAST 90 DAYS, etc.  See the [Relative Date Filter Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5) help article.